# How Can I update Custom index an array

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need some help in flutter and firestore. I have an object inside an array in my collocation Is there any way to update object custom an array?

Comment: The only way to update an item in array is: 1) to read the document with that array, 2) to update the array in your application code, 3) to write the array field back to the database. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123464/flutter-update-specific-index-in-list-firestore/59123491#59123491

Answer (score 0):

You can access and update anything inside an array by accessing it like you would any other array:

```dart
final List<SomeObject> _someObjects = <SomeObject>[];

...

for SomeObject s in _someObjects)
    doSomethingWith(s);
```

Comment: thank you I've  get the List from document and  I make modification list on memory after that send the list to the document  this way it's worked with  me